# how to add lightbox popup in Elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

**i want to add lightbox popup on full screen on click of every button that i add in elementor page.is that possible?**
i have  set button id but don't know how to use it in  plugin

[image: Here is image of my buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this plugin (popup maker) : https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/

It is very easy and Many option available in this plugin.
You can apply popup many place by apply class name only.

Comment: any other otption for that?